# jQuery Issue in IE7 Only

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-7

I have an issue popping up in IE7 only where it will issue a `"Object doesn't support the property or method"` error when the `onChange` event for any select box with a class of `VariationSelect`. I've thus narrowed it down to the following:

```
$(".VariationSelect").change(function() {
    // a bunch of irrelevant code
    // get the index of this select
    var index = $('.VariationSelect').index($(this)); //this is the line throwing the error in IE7
           //some code that returns a block of data in json formatting

});
```

My first thought was a section of code with `attr('disabled', 'disabled')` since I've previously had trouble with that in IE7 when removeAttr is also used, but even when I removed those lines, the error stayed the same and the line/char reference in the JS error (which is meaningless, of course) does not change. So do you see anything else in that code block that IE7 won't accept?

Edit: the code is running after a select box is changed. The select box HTML looks like the following:

```
<div class="DetailRow">
<div class="Label">Some Label:</div>
<div class="Value">
    <select name="variation[aNumberStartingAtOneAndIncrementingUpwards]" class="VariationSelect" id="VariationSelect" style="width: 180px;">
        <option value="">-- Choose an option --</option>
        {A bunch of options for this choice loaded by PHP}
    </select>
</div>
</div>
```

The quick and dirty way to do it, since I know that the name element will always have a number in it that is one greater than the index, is to grab the name from the element that changed with something like:

```
    var index = $(this).attr('name');
index = index.replace('variation[','');
index = index.replace(']','');
index = (index*1)-1;
```

Is there a faster/better way to get the index?

Comment: What is the property or method?  Have you run this with the debugger?

Comment: I think we'll need to see the code for `updateSelectedVariation`

Comment: When using that attr function in jQuery, it must be the only function you're running on the line.

To fix, I changed the code from:
$('.VariationSelect:eq(' + (index + 1) + ')').append(data.options).attr('disabled', '').focus();

to:

$('.VariationSelect:eq(' + (index + 1) + ')').append(data.options);
$('.VariationSelect:eq(' + (index + 1) + ')').attr('disabled', '');
$('.VariationSelect:eq(' + (index + 1) + ')').focus();

And it now works in IE7 and it continues to work in every other browser. I'm guessing I could probably combine the append and focus functions, but meh, it's working.

Comment: You might want to add that as an answer and accept it

Comment: Thanks, D3mon - I will. I tried, but apparently my score is too low to self-answer within 8 hours of the original question. Sorry for asking in the first place. I had been driving myself nuts for the last 6 hours trying to figure this one out. Hopefully the answer will save someone else that pain.

Comment: Edit - I take it all back. Not fixed. The problem has been limited to one line, however, and it is this one:

var index = $('.VariationSelect').index(this);

Is there some other way to get the index of the changed select box that has a class of VariationSelect?

Comment: @JoshuaWalcher That looks different to the line in your question. You have `.index($(this))` in your question (which is wrong btw) and `.index(this)` in your comment above

Comment: @Phil - Yes, you're right. Sorry about that. I have fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using that attr function in jQuery, it must be the only function you're running on the line.

To fix, I changed the code from:

```
    $('.VariationSelect:eq(' + (index + 1) + ')').append(data.options).attr('disabled', '').focus();
```

to:

```
    $('.VariationSelect:eq(' + (index + 1) + ')').append(data.options); $('.VariationSelect:eq(' + (index + 1) + ')').attr('disabled', ''); 
    $('.VariationSelect:eq(' + (index + 1) + ')').focus();
```

And it now works in IE7 and it continues to work in every other browser. I'm guessing I could probably combine the append and focus functions, but meh, it's working.